# Check if string has a certain format

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to check if a string respects a format that i give as input, for example:

From a list of strings i want to extract the one that has the following format:

```
***.***.***
```

where the * are all numbers.

I searched about regex but could not understand well enough to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick. The regex string is `^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$` Where I match each digit exactly 3 times, and check if a '.' separator is in the middle. ^ and $ signify the start and end of the string

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('^[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}$','111.222.333')
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10f98cb28>
>>> re.match('^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$','a11.22.33b')
>>> re.match('^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$','1a1.22.3b3')
>>> re.match('^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$','11.2a2.33')
```

Comment: it would also match `*.*.*`, `**.**.**`, `****.****.****`, etc. So not appropriate for the given format.

Comment: Edited accordingly

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a job for regex. A simple regex for that pattern might be

`\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\.\d\d\d`

The "\d" stands for any digit, and the "\." is an escaped period character (because "." is a special symbol in regex.) With python re library would probably use the findall method with that pattern,

`list_of_matches = re.findall("\d\d\d\.\d\d\d\.\d\d\d", my_string)`

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `re.findall` with the following pattern:

```
\b\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\b
```

Sample code:

```
input = "here some number 123.456.789 for testing"
matches = re.findall(r'\b\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{3}\b', input)
print(matches)

['123.456.789']
```

Using `re.findall` is a good choice here, because it also means that you can capture more than one match in the input string.